# Simplify for loop: read multiple files and remove specific data

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, leap-year

I have some 38 csv files in a folder of with rainfall data for multiple years as follows:

Precp_1980.csv

Precp_1981.csv

Precp_1982.csv

Precp_1983.csv
.
.
.

Precp_2017.csv

A leap year file looks like this:

```
Precp_1980 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(366*11299,min = 0, max = 4), ncol = 366, nrow = 11299)) 
names(Precp_1980) <- c(rep(paste0("d_",1:366)))
Precp_1980$ID1 <- seq(1:11299)
Precp_1980$ID2 <- seq(0.0,1.1, length.out = 11299)
Precp_1980$ID3 <- seq(1,10, length.out = 11299)
Precp_1980$ID4 <- seq(100,200, length.out = 11299)
Precp_1980$year<- 1980
```

One csv file has 11299 locations (11299 rows). The first four columns have some location specific information (`ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4`), fifth column has
`year` and column sixth till 371 column has daily rainfall data (i.e. 1 to 366 days).

A non-leap year file is exactly the same except it has one less column because of only 365 days:

```
Precp_1981 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(365*11299,min = 0, max = 4), ncol = 365, nrow = 11299))
names(Precp_1981) <- c(rep(paste0("d_",1:365)))
Precp_1981$ID1 <- seq(1:11299)
Precp_1981$ID2 <- seq(0.0,1.1, length.out = 11299)
Precp_1981$ID3 <- seq(1,10, length.out = 11299)
Precp_1981$ID4 <- seq(100,200, length.out = 11299)
Precp_1981$year<- 1981
```

My objective:

1) From all leap-year files, remove the doy 60 of the year so that all files have 365 days of the year.

2) Convert individual files from wide to long format

3) Combine all files into a single file

What I did was:

```
        library(data.table)
        library(dplyr)
        library(reshape2)

        year.list <- list() # create a list to save the outputs 
        yr.list <- c(1980:2017)
        leap.yr <- c(1980,1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016) # vector of leap years 

        for(y in seq_along(yr.list)){
            yr <- yr.list[y]

            if(yr %in% leap.yr){ # if a year is a leap year

              dat <- fread("Precp_",yr,".csv"))
              dat.up <- dat %>% dplyr::select(-d_60) # this removes the day 60 from the leap year 
              dat.up.m <- melt(dat.up, id.vars = c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","year"), value.name = "rain", variable.name = "day") # converts the data into long format
              dat.up.m <- dat.up.m %>% mutate(day = gsub("d_", "", day)) %>% # converts the "day_1" to numeric day of year
                                       mutate(day = as.numeric(day)) %>%
                                       mutate(day = ifelse(day >= 61, day - 1, day)) # this converts all days which were greater than 60 to previous day so that I have 365 days of year


            year.list[[y]]  <- dat.up.m
            } else { # if a year is not a leap year 
              dat <- fread("Precp_",yr,".csv"))
              dat.up.m <- melt(dat.up, id.vars = c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","year"), value.name = "rain", variable.name = "day") # converts the data into long format
              dat.up.m <- dat.up.m %>% mutate(day = gsub("d_", "", day)) %>% # converts the "day_1" to numeric day of year
                                        mutate(day = as.numeric(day)) %>%

              year.list[[y]]  <- dat.up.m

          }

          stack.rain <-  rbindlist(year.list)
```

I am looking for a shorter (maybe a faster?) solution. The script is too long

Comment: One caveat here, this command here `mutate(day = ifelse(day >= 61, 60, day)` sets all days bigger than 60 to 60, it does not subtract 1 for those dates.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't perform any complex data manipulations within loop.
In loop: load and `melt` all data (you won't be loosing much memory as you're removing only ~1/365 of the data).
Then outside the loop: using `data.table` object filter (remove day 60) and modify your data ("day" column).

```
# Arguments
yearAll <- 1980:2017
yearLp  <- seq(1980, 2016, 4)
# Libraries
library(data.table)
library(foreach)
# Load data
# It's possible to parallelize loop using %dopar%
result <- foreach(i = yearAll, .combine = rbind) %do% {
    melt(fread(paste0("Precp_", i, ".csv")), 
         c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "year"))
}
# Modify data
result <- result[!(year %in% yearLp & variable == "d_60")]
result[, day := as.numeric(sub("d_", "", variable))]
result[year %in% yearLp & day >= 61, day := day - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work. I loop through the files, reading everyone, but changing the `leap.years` on the go. There are maybe cleaner ways, but this one is simpler than yours.

```
year.list <- list() # create a list to save the outputs 
yr.list <- c(1980:2017)
leap.yr <- c(1980,1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016) # vector of leap years 

# function to read and clean data sets
data.prep = function(x){
  yy = fread("Precp_", x, ".csv")

  if(x %in% leap.yr){
    yy[, d_60 := NULL]

    cols = as.numeric(gsub("d_", "", names(yy)))
    cols = cols[!is.na(cols)]
    cols[cols > 60] = cols[cols > 60] - 1

    names(yy)[grep("d_", names(yy))] = cols
  } else {
    names(yy)[grep("d_", names(yy))] = paste(1:365)
  }
  return(yy)
}

xx = lapply(yr.list, data.prep))
names(xx) = paste(yr.list)
xx = rbindlist(xx, idcol = "year")

stack_rain <- melt(xx, id.vars = c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","year"),
                 value.name = "rain", variable.name = "day") # converts the data into long format
```